# which lib do I have to link for _wdupenv_s

Tags: c, mingw-w64

I download [python launcher](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PC/launcher.c)
and try to build it independently.

I have tried:
`gcc launcher.c -lversion -o py.exe`
`gcc launcher.o -lversion -lWs2_32 -o py.exe`

with both posix/win32 mingw-w64 and meet same error:

```
(.text+0x1b02): undefined reference to `__imp__wdupenv_s'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know there must be one more lib I have to link it, but I don't know which one.
Could anyone help?
or provide a method to find which lib contains specify function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_wdupenv_s()` had been apparently introduced in Visual Studio 2008's CRT (*msvcr90*), but it seems it didn't make it into the system CRT (*msvcrt*).  mingw-w64 GCCs generally link only to the system CRT by default so that's why `ld` can't find the symbol.

You can try to link to a Visual Studio CRT explicitly, but beware this might have bad consequences, because the resulting binary links to both CRTs and mixing CRTs is known to cause issues.

```
gcc -municode launcher.c -o launcher.exe -lversion -lmsvcr120
```

If your toolchain has that feature (the one built by MSYS2 has), you can replace the system CRT with the Visual Studio CRT completely:

```
gcc -municode -mcrtdll=msvcr120 launcher.c -o launcher.exe -lversion
```

I also added a `-municode` argument, otherwise I get an undefined reference to WinMain.

Also note that in [the build files](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/PCbuild) there's 4 binaries built from `launcher.c`, each with its own set of defines:

- `[...] -o pylauncher.exe -D_CONSOLE`
- `[...] -o pywlauncher.exe -D_WINDOWS`
- `[...] -o venvlauncher.exe -D_CONSOLE -DVENV_REDIRECT`
- `[...] -o venvwlauncher.exe -D_WINDOWS -DVENV_REDIRECT`

You should probably use one of these sets when compiling.

If you do a few more steps, you can even have a nice icon and stuff:

```
copy /y  ..\Include\patchlevel.h pythonnt_rc.h
echo #define FIELD3 106 >> pythonnt_rc.h
echo #define MS_DLL_ID "10.0" >> pythonnt_rc.h
echo #define PYTHON_DLL_NAME "foopython3.dll" >> pythonnt_rc.h
windres -I..\Include -I. pylauncher.rc -o pylauncher.o
gcc -municode -mcrtdll=msvcr120 -D_CONSOLE launcher.c pylauncher.o -o pylaunc
her.exe -lversion
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so if I wanna to avoid "links to both CRTs and mixing CRTs" problem, it's better use msvc instead of mingw?

Comment: On the off chance you're asking about msvcrt vs. msvcrNNN, then it's both mingw-w64. If you're really asking about mingw-w64 vs. MSVC, then it depends on what you're trying to achieve. The official Python is sadly MSVC-based, so if you're doing anything serious, it's probably best to follow that lead. If it's just a one-off launcher exe, mingw-w64 is more than fine.